# Quotation: If I quote a nickname for a team do I have to quote it everytime I use it?

Tags: quotes

I'm writing an essay about the violence caused by Manchester United fans during the 1990s. In the article I'm basing my essay off of they say they call themselves "Jibbers." If I quote the nikcname and provide insight citation do I have to continue to quote it each time or what would I do so its not plagiarism.

Comment: Are you basing your essay *on* the fact that the fans call *themselves* "Jibbers"?  By "insight citation," do you mean "inline citation"?  The quotes around the first quoted word mean that I'm calling attention to the word as a word.  I'm not quoting anyone, and you're probably not either.  If you wish to give a source for the fact that the fans call themselves by a nickname, that's fine, and most manuals of style will require a citation at first use only.  But you can't plagiarize a fact, just other people's phrasing.

Comment: Im basing my essay on the violence the fans caused but instead of saying over and over again Machester United fans the term Jibber is shorter and easier to use. Yes sorry inline citation. I handed in a copy of my paper already and when my professor gave it back he put around the word quotation marks. What I'm asking is after the first use of the word Jibber do I have to do anything when I use it a second or third or fourth time?

Comment: The article isn't actually an article is just a portion of a book. The sentence from the book is "The Inter-City Jibbers themselves were also divided..." I couldn't find the other quote I mentioned but this is close enough to work. So in my essay I wrote "commonly called "Jibbers" they...." So after my first usage of the word do I need to keep quoting it over and over again?

Comment: Once you've defined a term for your readers, you should be able to use it freely.  This is a matter of style, which will be dictated by your professor.  Did you ask him (or her)?  *The Chicago Manual of Style* uses either quotation marks or italics for situations like first use of a nickname or a special word.

Comment: I didn't ask but on the draft copy of the paper he put quotation marks around it. He didn't put any marks around the other times I used it. I'm just going to use it freely and hopefully I'll be okay.

Comment: *CMS* allows for the designation "so called" before a popular usage.  They leave the word following in Roman type, unquoted.  You could also use *soi-disant* for "so called by themselves."  It sounds like your prof wants quotes around the definition and no quotes around its subsequent usage.  Whether that's standard or not (and I think it's common) you should go with what was marked.

Comment: @Matt I'm not sure whether you're referring mainly to quotation marks or to citations, but if it's a fact that you're using multiple times in the same way, in the same paper, you only need to cite it the first time. For example, if you said "50% of Company Y's sales came from Asia", you wouldn't need to include a citation every time you mentioned that fact again in the paper.